# How to update user profile photo with msgraph-sdk-java?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Here is what I have so far:

```
    ProfilePhoto photo = new ProfilePhoto();
    photo.???


    IProfilePhotoRequest request = graphServiceClient.users(userId).photo().buildRequest();
    request.patch(photo, new ICallback<ProfilePhoto>(){
        @Override
        public void success(final ProfilePhoto result) {

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(ClientException e) {

        }
    });
```

However I don't know how to set the 'Binary data for the image':

PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
Content-type: image/jpeg

Binary data for the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [**BaseProfilePhotoStreamRequest**](http://thttps://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/3ceabf41edad5ca36abb775536c4abe9d4ec9c0b/src/main/java/com/microsoft/graph/requests/generated/BaseProfilePhotoStreamRequest.java) but not the one in your code. Such thing like:

```
IBaseProfilePhotoStreamRequest request = graphServiceClient.users(userId).photo().getContent().buildRequest();
request.put(imageBytes);
```

Reference Code to get image binary:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;   
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;   
import java.io.File;   
import java.io.IOException;   

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;   

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;   
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;   

public class TestImageBinary {   
    static BASE64Encoder encoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();   
    static BASE64Decoder decoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder();   

    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        System.out.println(getImageBinary());   

        base64StringToImage(getImageBinary());   
    }   

    static String getImageBinary(){   
        File f = new File("c://20090709442.jpg");          
        BufferedImage bi;   
        try {   
            bi = ImageIO.read(f);   
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   
            ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", baos);   
            byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();   

            return encoder.encodeBuffer(bytes).trim();   
        } catch (IOException e) {   
            e.printStackTrace();   
        }   
        return null;   
    }  
}
```

Comment: That is a great start, thank you for the suggestion.  Could you be more specific about IBaseProfilePhotoStreamRequest?  I am good with encoding the image, what I am having trouble with is figuring out how to make the request using the SDK.

Comment: @user3026344 The code has been modified and may still require some minor adjustments

Comment: Ah, something isn't right.  So there is no getContent(), instead, there is content().  Also, this fails 

IBaseProfilePhotoStreamRequest request = graphServiceClient.users(userId).photo().getContent().buildRequest();
request.put(imageBytes);  with a cast exception where BufferedInputStream can't be cast to ProfilePhoto